# k-NN, SVM and RF Models Taking Too Long with caret Package in R

Tags: r, model, r-caret

I have a data frame with about 1.2 Million Observations over five columns with a sample below:

```
   plate_x plate_z release_speed release_spin_rate Whiff
1     0.16    3.92          91.7              2195     0
2     0.21    3.37          91.2              2161     0
3    -1.25    3.26          94.0              2233     0
4    -0.86    2.17          94.2              2220     0
5    -0.07    1.89          93.4              2217     0
6    -0.47    3.42          91.3              2215     0
7     0.50    4.25          92.5              2276     0
8    -0.65    3.01          91.3              2256     0
9    -0.27    3.26          91.5              2179     0
10    0.63    3.89          92.2              2175     0
11    0.35    2.90          95.3              2412     0
12   -0.60    3.84          85.8              2097     0
13   -0.68    2.18          95.7              2493     0
14   -0.24    3.79          94.4              2058     1
15    0.26    4.50          95.6              2533     0
16   -0.62    2.68          95.1              2006     0
17    0.60    3.34          94.2              2026     0
18   -0.69    1.83          95.0              2671     0
19   -0.84    1.81          94.0              2475     0
20   -1.23    3.91          86.9              2211     0
```

When I run a LDA it takes about ~5 minutes and a CART it takes about ~10-15 minutes.
Using an 80% train / 20 % test using the code below:

```
validation_index <- createDataPartition(dataset$Whiff, p=0.80, list=FALSE)
validation <- dataset[-validation_index,]
dataset <- dataset[validation_index,]
```

With Whiff being a factor (1,0) whether the variables happens or not, and four other variables, all numeric attempting to predict whether the whiff will happen. I use the code to run the models below:

```
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10)
metric <- "Accuracy"


set.seed(7)
fit.lda <- train(Whiff~., data=dataset, method="lda", metric=metric, trControl=control)
# CART
set.seed(7)
fit.cart <- train(Swing_Value~., data=dataset, method="rpart", metric=metric, trControl=control)
# kNN
set.seed(7)
fit.knn <- train(Swing_Value~., data=dataset, method="knn", metric=metric, trControl=control)
# c) advanced algorithms
# SVM
set.seed(7)
fit.svm <- train(Swing_Value~., data=dataset, method="svmRadial", metric=metric, trControl=control)
# Random Forest
set.seed(7)
fit.rf <- train(Swing_Value~., data=dataset, method="ranger", metric=metric, trControl=control)
```

However the latter three take too long, that its never actually finished >= 5 hours.
Is there any way to speed this process up. I'm new to this, so I'm not sure if this actually is the average time or if I'm doing something that is inefficient.

Comment: you are fitting about 100 models each time for knn, svm and rf.. so the first question would be is this nessecary?

Answer (score 0):

You can parallel process in the `caret` package and this can speed things up considerably depending on how many cores you have.

As an example, you set up the number of cores first before you start to train.

Note: `|>` is new as of R 4.1.0 as a base pipe. If you do not have this version then just nest `makePSOCKcluster(detectCores())` or use the `%>%` pipe operator from `magrittr`.

```
library(doParallel)

cl <- parallel::detectCores() |>
  parallel::makePSOCKcluster()

# this will use all cores, consider doing length(cl) - some number
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl, cores = length(cl))
```

You will see in the documentation to `caret::trainControl` the argument `allowParallel` is by default `TRUE`.

Comment: So I run this, and then run the models the same way as previously? Or do I need to adjust the prior code to account for the parallel.

Comment: As a test run a single `train` after setting this up. As it is running check your computer's CPU usage and it should spike since many of the cores are going towards this process.

Comment: I noticed some strange behaviour - 1. some of caret's methods don't support `doParallel`. 2. the ones that are compatible, in my experience, all take vastly longer (~3x) to run WITH `doParallel` active, despite much higher CPU utilization.